# Django filter for ManyToMany items which exist only in a specified list

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I have the following:

```
class Category():
    category_group = models.ManyToManyField("CategoryGroup", blank=True, related_name="category_group")

class CategoryGroup():
    label = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)


categories = Category.objects.exclude(category_group__label__in=["keywords_1", "keywords_2"]
```

I wish to exclude the categories whose group label exists in either `keywords_1` or `keywords_2` only. If a category group label exists in `keywords_1` and `keywords_3` I do not want to exclude it. What changes are needed for this query?

Comment: What if these exist in both `keywords_1` and `keywords_2`?

Comment: Please clarify what kind of queryset do you exactly want as you stated to exclude if group label exists in `keywords1` and `keywords2`, ok but at the same time you're saying **If a category group label exists in keywords_1 and keywords_3 I do not want to exclude it**, here you again need a queryset which will not exclude `keywords1`?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem if they exist in both then exclude. But if they exist in both and also `keywords_3` then do not exclude.

Comment: @SunderamDubey yes if they exist in either `keywords_1 ` and/or `keywords_2` ONLY, then exclude.

Comment: @KvnH: what for `Category`s that have no keywords?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem by default they will all have at least one keyword

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter out such items by looking for `Category`s that have at least one item that is not `keywords_1`/`keywords_2`, or have no items, so:

```
from django.db.models import Exists, OuterRef, Q

Category.objects.filter(
    Exists(
        CategoryGroup.objects.filter(
            ~Q(label__in=['keywords1', 'keywords2']),
            category_group=OuterRef('pk'),
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: But if a Category has a group label in `keywords_1`/`keywords_2` as well as any other label I wish to include it in the result too. 
This answer still excludes categories where the group label exists in `keywords_1` and `any_other_keyword`. In this case I would wish to include it.

Comment: @KvnH: but we do not check if the keyword is keywords1/keywords_2, we check if there is anything that is *not* such keyword. Updated with an exists subquery.